# Unremovable Grub2Win Boot Manager. Windows 10 No Uninstall Button

Tags: windows-10, debian, grub2

**I installed debian and other debian distro.** But debian's bootloader couldn't list the other debian based OS. *So i installed Grub2Win on my old 2011 32Bit laptop.* There isnt a uninstall button and even though i ran fixboot, fixmbr, with bootrec it still doesnt solve my problems, i deleted the folder for grub2win, still, it appears on my screen even though it's not bootable. I need help cuz i cant access debian anymore, and don't want to install the OS again just to get GRUB :/ . I dont want to loose any data any help is appreciated. The folder I deleted is Grub2Win on my C:\ drive

Comment: it's Grub2Win tho not GRUB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grub2Win now uses the standard Windows uninstall from the Windows control panel.

The old blue uninstall button is gone since version 2.1.4.6 released in mid July.

Comment: Thanks it worked flawlessly!

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

- Reinstall Grub2Win
- Run it and click the blue "Uninstall" button on the main screen

This will remove all Grub2Win files and directories and delete the BIOS
entry.

Comment: There is no "Uninstall Button"

Comment: Run the installation again and it will be there - see it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4jwPO7HWljQ) (on Windows). Otherwise, just delete the Linux partition inside the EFI partition from Windows ([link](https://askubuntu.com/a/869888/963426)).

Comment: I have already decided to run the installer several times already, and I didn't want to delete my linux partition.  Thanks anyway :)